# how to check the remote BORG version

Tags: borg-backup

We are using a hosted BORG service and get these warnings when initializing a repo:

```
By default repositories initialized with this version will produce security
errors if written to with an older version (up to and including Borg 1.0.8).

If you want to use these older versions, you can disable the check by running:
borg upgrade --disable-tam 'ssh://USER@HOST/./dmapp'

See https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html#pre-1-0-9-manifest-spoofing-vulnerability for details about the security implications.
```

I guess that the local version does not match the remote version. Can anyone confirm this?
Is there a way to check the remote BORG version?

According to the docs the remote version should be 1.1

My local version:

```
borg --version
borg 1.1.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cited message does not indicate that the remote version is out-dated, but notifies you that attempts to write to the repository with an outdated client will raise errors.

The message is also displayed if you create a **local repository**:

```
$ borg init -e repokey $(mktemp -d)
Enter new passphrase: 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Do you want your passphrase to be displayed for verification? [yN]: y
Your passphrase (between double-quotes): "test"
Make sure the passphrase displayed above is exactly what you wanted.

By default repositories initialized with this version will produce security
errors if written to with an older version (up to and including Borg 1.0.8).

If you want to use these older versions, you can disable the check by running:
borg upgrade --disable-tam /tmp/tmp.9Fc74B7qj9

See https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html#pre-1-0-9-manifest-spoofing-vulnerability for details about the security implications.

IMPORTANT: you will need both KEY AND PASSPHRASE to access this repo!
Use "borg key export" to export the key, optionally in printable format.
Write down the passphrase. Store both at safe place(s).
```

To answer your question's second part: There is no way - I am aware of - to check the remote version of borg. However, you can check the repository's version using `borg config -l <REPO>`:

```
$ borg config -l /tmp/tmp.9Fc74B7qj9/
[repository]
version = 1
segments_per_dir = 1000
max_segment_size = 524288000
storage_quota = 0
additional_free_space = 0
append_only = 0
id = 429642bc7ac26c28daa69f7d4654c36a07a15b5d1ca3eb6b0d4a264c677689dc
```

Hope this helps and happy backuping ;)